# Contador de letras repetidas. #python

Tags: python, lista, string, caracteres, return

¿Alguno podría ayudarme armar una función que me retorne la posición de la letra que más se repitió?
Es decir, que si escribo "casa", debería retornarme las 2 posiciones donde se repite la letra A.

Luego el valor de esa función se debe agregar a una lista que va a guardar esas posiciones, hasta ahora solo armé la parte del agregado:  (no está terminado)

```py
def guardado():
    lista=[]
    for i in range (valores_de_la_primerFuncion):
        lista.append(i)
    return lista
```

Comment: Has intentado algo siquiera? Porque de ser el caso, asumo que te han tirado errores, allí nisiquiera tienes tu variable interable definida, pareciera mas que es un ejercicio de clase y pides que la resolvamos

Comment: Para contar las repeticiones de elementos en un iterable te recomiendo el objeto estándar [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Para conocer las posiciones de los elementos a medida que los iteras te recomiendo iterar con [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado (como texto, con formato) y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. [**Aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Existen métodos ya implementados que puedes usar como collections.Counter().

Pero parece que estás aprendiendo, así que este código podría serte de ayuda para entender cómo usar objetos de python como los diccionarios y los DataFrame de pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

string = "casa"

def mayor_ocurrencia(string):
    
    #Diccionario vacío, en este se lleva la cuenta de las letras,
    #el número de veces que aparecen y las posiciones en las que 
    #están
    dictionary = {}
    for i, s in enumerate(string):
        #enummerate retorna el índice i de la letra y la letra s del string
        if s not in dictionary.keys():
            #Si es una letra nueva (no está en las claves del diccionario) 
            #se agrega a este
            dictionary.update({s: {"count" : 1, "position" : [i]}})
        else:
            #Si ya está, se suma uno al contador de apariciones y se agrega 
            #el index i de su posición
            dictionary[s]["count"] +=1
            dictionary[s]["position"].append(i)
    # Se transforma el diccionario a un dataframe de pandas porque su
    # indexación y uso de funciones es bastante sencilla
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
    # Se transpone el DataFrame para que las letras sean los índices de las filas
    df = df.transpose()
    
    # Se filtra la letra con mayor ocurrencia
    df_mayor = df[df["count"] == df["count"].max()]
    return df_mayor

mayor_ocurrencia(string)
```

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_. [es.so] no es un sitio del tipo _hazme la tarea_ o similares.

Comment: Haz caso a lo que te dicen... aquí no está muy bien visto hacerle los deberes a nadie. Pero si vas a hacerlo, intenta hacerlo ciñéndote a lo que le piden. Cuando un alumno está empezando a aprender python no es normal que meta pandas para hacer un ejercicio tan absurdamente básico. De hecho, uno de los motivos por el que no se deben responder preguntas que son claramente ejercicios de clase es porque no tienes toda la información necesaria para hacerlo normalmente, puesto que no sabes qué puede usar o no. Esto no es elrincondelprogramadorvago, esto es SO.